# Richfaces scripts / styles not loading

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces

I have a simple scrollableDataTable in a jsf

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<!-- RichFaces tag library declaration -->
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
<f:view>


<h:form>
  <div id="contentvoll">
   <div id="contenttabelle">
    <rich:scrollableDataTable value="#{searchBean.searchList}" styleClass="fullTable" rowClasses="odd,even" var="elem" id="suchTable"
    first="1" rows="50" rowKeyVar="activeRow" activeRowKey="#{searchBean.activeRowKey}" frozenColCount="1">
     <rich:column>
      <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="Firmennummer"></h:outputText>
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{elem.firmnr}"></h:outputText>
     </rich:column>
     <rich:column>
      <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="Firmenname"></h:outputText>
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{elem.fname1}"></h:outputText>
     </rich:column>
    </rich:scrollableDataTable>
   </div>
   <div class="update"></div>
  </div>
 </h:form>
</f:view>
```

I think I'm doing something wrong because this produces me only a table which I can't scroll and where the cols are overlapping.  Seems like the javascript which is needed isn't loaded. I include this into template

```
<script src="/portal/faces/rfRes/org/ajax4jsf/framework.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/portal/faces/rfRes/org/richfaces/ui.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My web.xml

```
<context-param>
<param-name>org.ajax4jsf.RESOURCE_URI_PREFIX</param-name>
<param-value>rfRes</param-value>
</context-param>


<filter>
<display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
<filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- JSF configuration -->
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
<param-value>NONE</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
<param-value>NONE</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.portlet.faces.renderPolicy</param-name>
<param-value>NEVER_DELEGATE</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Faces Servlet -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup> 1 </load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Faces Servlet Mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Does anyone has faced the same problem?

Comment: Solved: Problem was that the style weren't loaded this caused the overlapping and not triggering the ajax event which occurs while scrolling.

Comment: So you changed the loadStyleStrategy to ALL, as suggested? Or used another approach?

Comment: I've changed loadStyleStrategy to ALL but leaved loadScriptStrategy to NONE - I preffer to include the scripts on my own in my template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This will load everything automatically.

However, if you don't want it (for some reason), you should use (instead of `<script>`):

```
<a4j:loadScript src="resource:///org/ajax4jsf/framework.pack.js" />
```

(or `<a4j:loadStyle />` for css)

Because it adds a .jsp / .jsf suffix, but you aren't supposed to use it that way in the common case.

Comment: Changeing the context-params to all doesn't has an effect sadly. Anyways the framework.pack.js is loaded.

Comment: so, now what's the problem? Did you check the firefox error console for concrete JS errors?